# How to display RECOMMENDED category in magento

Tags: php, magento, wamp

I am new in magento platform.

I want to display recommended product category in the product page.

I have some codes but its not working properly.

it will show all the products, instead of just the recommended categories.

Recommended product cat I am taking product adding time.

my code is

```
<?php
    $product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $pr_data = $_product->getData();
    ?>
    <?php if ($pr_data['recommended_categories']): ?>
        <?php
        $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
        $category->load($categoryid);
        $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        ?>
        <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 cpl-xs-12">  
            <div class="ndlSimilarTop">
                <div class="ndlSimilatProductTitle">RECOMMENDED PRODUCTS</div>
                <div id="amazingcarousel-container-1" style="overflow:hidden">
                    <div id="amazingcarousel-1" style="display:block;position:relative;width:100%;max-width:711px;margin:0px auto 0px;">
                        <div class="amazingcarousel-list-container" style="overflow:hidden;">
                            <ul class="amazingcarousel-list">
                                <?php foreach ($collection as $_item): ?>
                                    <li class="amazingcarousel-item">
                                        <div class="amazingcarousel-item-container">
                                            <div class="amazingcarousel-image">
                                                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(217, 173) ?>"  alt="product-img" />

                                                <ul class="mask mask1">
                                                    <li class="ndlHoverContent ndlHoverContent1">
                                                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="ndlListWishlist ndlListWishlist1 ndlListWishlist2"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>images/wishlist-white-icon.png" alt="">Add to wishlist</a>
                                                        <a href="#" class="ndlListAddtobag ndlListAddtobag1 ndlListAddtobag2"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>images/mybag-white-icon.png" alt="">Add to bag</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="ndlListDetail">
                                                <div class="ndlProductListName"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></div>
                                                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$categoryid
```

is undefined when you do:

```
$category->load($categoryid);
```

Set it to the 'Recommended' category id you wish to display.

Comment: i put here recommended cat ids but still it will showing product not category.i want to show categories name.

 

    $category->load($pr_data['recommended_categories']);

Comment: Sorry could you clarify your intent. What is the end goal here? Is it to get product names output within your recommended category and additional product attributes/details?

Comment: here i will get product name .  but i want to display Recommended product Categories Like ,,,,,,,,my Recommended product Categories is 45, and 67.....i want to display in Recommended product Categories only  45, and 67 (45 and 46 is the Categories  id's)

Comment: if( $categoryid == 45 ) ?

Comment: if i have multiple category then it will showing only one category products

Comment: Add the categories you want in an array and loop through it for allowed categories to load each category and products wherein.